# How to crop UIImage when scrolled in UIScrollView

Tags: swift, xcode

I have created scrollview with a label and rectangle. The rectangle is created programmatically.
When scrolled, the label is working fine, i.e. it is moving up and hiding when it hits the boundary of the view. However the rectangle is moving up, but it is not hiding (cropping) at the boundary.

**Example: step 1**

[image: Image 1]

**Example: step 2**

[image: Image 2]

Here is the code of the rectangle:

```
let timelineBar = UIView()
    timelineBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(displayP3Red: 119/255, green: 140/255, blue: 163/255, alpha: 1)
    view.addSubview(timelineBar)timelineBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
timelineBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
timelineBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.heightAnchor).isActive = true
timelineBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
timelineBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -250).isActive = true
timelineBar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.widthAnchor, constant: -250).isActive = true
```

I tried implementing image zooming examples, I found on the Internet, but I could not make them work.

I use XCode 11.7.

Answer (score 0):

I am stupid.
There was mistake of improperly assigning image to view not to scrollable view.
This line: view.addSubview(timelineBar)
Had to be changed to this: contentView.addSubview(timelineBar)

Apart from this, I am curious why the image was scrolled even though it was not assigned to scrollable view.